# Login Failed Symfony Angular

Tags: angular, symfony

Cuando intento hacer el login desde el navegador, me devuelve el mensaje de error "login failed" (que lo arroja desde dentro del servicio de JwtAuth), lo extraño es que si lo hago desde postman con las mismas credenciales, me loguea correctamente devolviendo el token. Que podria estar mal? el código lo he revisado varias veces.

He hecho pruebas y he conseguido que me devuelva el token poniendole la contraseña encriptada, pero si le pongo admin (que es la contraseña que le puse al usuario) sin mas: "login failed".

Añado fotos de mi código, porque la verdad no veo el error por ningún lado, y el fallo esta en que no debe de encriptar la contraseña para compararla con la que hay en la base de datos, porque no tengo errores en consola ni nada, es extrañisimo esto, o me comi algo o no lo entiendo...

JwtAuth service:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class JwtAuth{

public $manager;
public $key;

public function __construct($manager){
    $this-> manager = $manager;
    $this-> key = 'soytuclavesecreta12344321';
}
public function signup($email,$password, $getHash = null){
    //Buscamos en la base de datos el usuario con findOneBy
    $user = $this->manager->getRepository('BackendBundle:User')->findOneBy(array(
        "email" => $email,
        "password" => $password
    ));
    $signup = false;
    if(is_object($user)){
        $signup = true;
    }
    if($signup ==true){
        //generar token
        $token = array(
            'sub' => $user->getId(),
            'email' => $user->getEmail(),
            'name' => $user->getName(),
            'surname' => $user->getSurname(),
            'iat' => time(),
            'exp' => time()+(7*24*60*60)
        );

        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $this->key, 'HS256');
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $this->key, array('HS256'));

        if($getHash == null){
            $data = $jwt;
        }else{
            $data = $decoded;
        }

    }else{
        $data = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'data'=> 'Login failed'
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
public function checkToken($jwt,$getIdentity = false){
    $auth = false;
    try{
        $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $this->key, array('HS256'));
    }catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e){
        $auth = false;
    }catch(\DomainException $e){
        $auth = false;
    }
    if(is_object($decoded) && isset($decoded -> sub)){
        $auth = true;
    }else{
        $auth = false;
    }
    if($getIdentity == false){
        return $auth;
    }else{
        return $decoded;
    }
}
}
```

login component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
@Component({
 selector: 'login',
 templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
 providers: [UserService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{
 public title: string;
 public user;
 public identity;
 public token;
 constructor(
 private _route: ActivatedRoute,
 private _router: Router,
 private _userService: UserService
 ){
 this.title = 'Identifícate';
 this.user = {
 "email":"",
 "password":"",
 "gethash": "false"
 };
 }
 ngOnInit(){
 console.log('El componente login.component ha sido cargado');
 console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')));
 this.logout();
 this.redirectIfIdentity();
 }

 onSubmit(){
 console.log(this.user);
 this._userService.signup(this.user).subscribe(
 response => {
 this.identity = response;
 if(this.identity.length <= 1){
 console.log('Error en el servidor');
 }{
 if(!this.identity.status){
 localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));
 //get token
 this.user.getHash=null;
 this._userService.signup(this.user).subscribe(
 response => {
 this.token = response;
 if(this.identity.length <= 1){
 console.log('Error en el servidor');
 }{
 if(this.identity.status){
 localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(this.identity));

 //window.location.href= "/";
 }
 }
 },
 error => {
 console.log(<any>error)
 }
 );
 }
 }
 },
 error => {
 console.log(<any>error)
 }
 );
 }
```

user service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { GLOBAL } from './global';
@Injectable()
export class UserService{

 public url: string;
 public identity;
 public token;
 constructor(private _http: Http){
 this.url = GLOBAL.url;
 }
 signup(user_to_login){
 let json = JSON.stringify(user_to_login);
 let params = "json="+json;
 let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
 return this._http.post(this.url+'/login', params, {headers: headers})
 .map(res => res.json());
 }
```

login html:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

 <h3>{‌{title}}</h3>

 <div class="identity_alert alert alert-success" *ngIf= "identity && identity.sub">
 Te has logueado correctamente Bienvenido {‌{identity.email}}
 </div>

 <div class="identity_alert alert alert-danger" *ngIf= "identity && identity.data">
 No te has logueado correctamente
 </div>

 <form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class = "col-md-7 no-padding">

 <p>
 <label>Email:</label>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.email" required/>
 <span *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched">El email no es válido</span>
 </p>

 <p>
 <label>Contraseña:</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" #password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.password" 
 required/>
 <span *ngIf="!password.valid && password.touched">La contraseña no es válida</span>
 </p>

 <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-primary"[disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid"/>

 </form>
</div>
```

Adjunto tambien imagenes del navegador:

Antes de hacer el login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Logueando con contraseña normal:
[image: Logueando con contraseña normal:]
Logueando con la contraseña encriptada de la bd:
[image: Logueando con la contraseña encriptada de la bd:]
Muchas gracias anticipadas.

Edito: Se me olvido poner el codigo del Controlador que se encarga de la encriptacion de la contraseña:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

public function indexAction(Request $request){
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    ]);
}

public function loginAction(Request $request){
    $helpers = $this->get(Helpers::class);
    //Recibir json por POST
    $json = $request->get('json', null);
    //Arrray a devolver
    $data = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'data' => 'Send json via POST !'
    );
    if($json != null){
        //Convertimos json a un objeto de php 
        $params = json_decode($json);

        $email = (isset($params->email)) ? $params->email : null;
        $password = (isset($params->password)) ? $params->password : null;
        $getHash = (isset($params->getHash)) ? $params->getHash : null;

        $emailConstraint = new Assert\Email();
        $emailConstraint->message = "This email is not valid";
        $validate_email = $this->get("validator")->validate($email, $emailConstraint);

        //Cifrar la contraseña
        $pwd = hash('sha256',$password);

        if($email != null && count($validate_email) == 0 && $password != null){

            $jwt_auth = $this->get(JwtAuth::class);

            if($getHash == null || $getHash ==false){
                $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $password);
            }else{
                $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $password, true);
            }
            return $this->json($signup);
        }else{
            $data = array(
                'status' => 'Error',
                'data' => 'Email or password incorrect'
            );
        }
    }
    return $helpers->json($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que esta sucediendo es que estás enviando el *$password* en texto plano y al realizar la consulta por *$email* y *$password* este no se encuentra en base de datos ya que lo guardas encriptado. Es por esto que pasa directamente al bloque:

```
$data = array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'data'=> 'Login failed'
);
```

Necesitarías encriptar la variable *$password* antes de realizar la consulta. Ignoro con qué método encriptaste el password al ser guardado en la base de datos pero de haber utilizado un *key* necesitarías utilizarla para que coincida con el registro en base de datos.

Tendría que ser algo así:

```
...
public function signup($email, $password, $getHash = null) {

    $password = $encode->encoder($password, $key);

    $user = $this->manager->getRepository('BackendBundle:User')->findOneBy(array(
        "email" => $email,
        "password" => $password
    ));
...
```

Suponiendo que *$encode* contiene un método *encoder* que recibe dos parámetros que son el *password* a encriptar y el *key*.

**UPDATE**

```
    //Cifrar la contraseña
    $pwd = hash('sha256',$password);

    if($email != null && count($validate_email) == 0 && $password != null){

        $jwt_auth = $this->get(JwtAuth::class);

        if($getHash == null || $getHash ==false){
            // $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $password);
            $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $pwd);
        }else{
            // $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $password, true);
            $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $pwd, true);
        }
        return $this->json($signup);
    }else{
        $data = array(
            'status' => 'Error',
            'data' => 'Email or password incorrect'
        );
    }
```

Al momento de encriptar la contraseña `$pwd = hash('sha256', $password);` no estás enviando la variable `$pwd` en el método `$jwt_auth->signup($email, $pwd);`

Solo debes de cambiar esas dos líneas y funcionará.

Comment: He editado el codigo, para mostrarte como hago la encriptacion de la contraseña, se me habia olvidado poner el controlador

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Angel, lo he solucionado. gran aporte :) menuda tonteria en verdad..

Comment: Y por casualidad no sabrás decirme donde guarda symfony las sesiones cuando se loguea un usuario? porque estoy poniendo que tenga que estar identificado y que devuelva datos del usuario logueado por ejemplo para modificar sus datos, pero no muestra ningun dato, eso quiere decir que no me esta guardando las credenciales de usuario ni el token ni nada. Se agradece la ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Tiene algún tiempo que ya no trabajo con Symfony así que no podría ayudarte del todo por ahora, pero seguro que si publicas tu pregunta te ayudarán. Saludos.